# Unity how to change all pixels of the same color to another color?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For example, I have a png file and I want to turn all pixels in a png file that has the same RGB value into another color. I am working on an interactive map with provinces and I want to have a file where all provinces have different RGB values and use province colors as an id system. Problem is that I don't know how to change RGB value to another

Answer (score 1):

If its a Texture2D, you can change the pixels as follow:

```
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(128, 128); // load your texture here
Color colortrigger = Color.Blue; // color triggers to change
for (int y = 0; y < texture.height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < texture.width; x++)
    {
        if(texture.GetPixel(x,y) == colortrigger)
        {
           // Change the pixel to another color
           texture.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Yellow);              
        }
    }
}
texture.Apply();
```

Comment: Will this work if that texture is turned in the material which is put on the sphere

Comment: Yes, you just have to get the corresponding material on that sphere and get the texture from the material with [Material.GetTexture()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.GetTexture.html)

Comment: Ok I will try this